# Design layout Xamarin Android bugado Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

Fala galera, baixei o Visual Studio 2019 com Xamarin para trabalhar em um projeto, porém quando eu abro um layout para poder trabalhar a tela vem toda em branco, os objetos estão ali mas não aparecem. Alguém pode me ajudar?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode tentar alterar o Tema, lá onde diz "AppCompat". Porém, se isso não adiantar, provavelmente você criou seu layout de forma errada, pois normalmente o que mostra no "Design" de uma tela é o que você vai ver no aplicativo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @perozzo, já alterei o tema e nada adiantou. E nesse caso eu escolhi um app pré montado que já vem com xamarin de exemplo. tentei também criando um novo app em branco e também com um já existente que estou trabalhando, porém na versão do 2015 do VS.

Comment: E quando você executa o aplicativo, a tela que está falando é mostrada normalmente ou aparece em branco também?

Comment: Sim, quando o app é executado tudo funciona normalmente, o problema é ai no design mesmo.

Comment: Que estranho isso... Se nem fechando e abrindo de novo der certo, sugiro dar um repair na instalação do VS.